# PDFTK not executing from Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, pdftk, php-pdftk

I am creating a Wordpress plugin that utilizes PDFTK. I followed the documentation for php-pdftk and my PHP looks like this:

```
$pdf = new Pdf('/pdf-templates/testpdf.pdf', ['command' => 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe',
            'useExec' => true]);
            $pdf->fillForm($data)
            ->flatten()
            ->saveAs('/generated-pdfs/' . $filename);
```

I installed php-pdftk using composer and the commands follow through fine. I installed pdftk using
`sudo apt-get install pdftk` and it runs correctly in my Ubuntu terminal. I am developing on a local version of Wordpress hosted in a Docker container with a WSL2 backend.

I have tried installing pdftk locally to my windows machine and passing the path directly as well as using the Ubuntu installation, but neither command passes and both fail. I used the methods from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367121/pdftk-not-executing-in-php) to check whether the command was executing and it isn't, which leaves me to believe that my path is the issue, but even passing the absolute path through did not help. I believe it may be something to do with using Docker. This needs to be usable on a live server as well, so I want to avoid using the local windows install but I needed to test if that would work either. I am totally stumped, and any help would be greatly appreciated

I should also mention that even after installing the local version of pdftk, Powershell, CMD and Git Bash did not register it as a command, but I assumed that since I was passing the hard path to the application it didnt matter if my windows PATH was wrong

Comment: Is your problem related to WordPress or even PHP yet, or is pdftk not working on a Linux CLI your actual problem, I can’t quite tell.

Comment: From what I can tell it should be working on the Linux CLI, running pdftk in Ubuntu returns as expected, but it doesn't execute from the PHP script